# How to get data for an item When User clicks on ListBox Item without PostBack in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a ListBox, which has miltiple items in it.
Now When User Click on any any , I want to show some data related to that particular item and this data will come from database.

I want to handle this from Client Side, So is This possible that User cliks on an item and He will get information related to that item from DB. 
I want to use ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender for this purpose.

So Please tell me is this possible by using BalloonPopupExtender.

Or is there any other way round, please let me know.

I have two options.
one is initially I can get data for all the items and store it some where and When User click on a particular item, I will display data related to that particular item.
second is When User clicks on an item at that time only I get data from DB.

Please tell me what is best way.
If its possible by using javascript also, Please suggest me, as I'm new to javascript.

Comment: As you have already pointed out, AJAX is the way to go.

Comment: But I dont know how :(